# Phaser button handler function with parameter

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing, phaser-framework

I'm using Phaser.js to build an html game. This maybe more of a general javascript question but I'm using Phaser as context, so I try to setup a button with handler, here's the button definition in main.js:

```
var someParam = 2;
var btn = game.add.button(0, 0, 'playButton', actions.handler, this, 1, 0, 1);
```

And in another file named actions.js, I defined the handler function:

```
var handler = function(someParam) {
    console.log(someParam);
};
module.exports = {
    handler: handler
};
```

Question is how can I pass that someParam into the handler function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Phaser but in JavaScript you have two possible options:

1)

```
game.add.button(0, 0, 'playButton', function(){
  actions.handler(someParam);
}, this, 1, 0, 1);
```

2)

```
game.add.button(0, 0, 'playButton',actions.handler.bind(this,someParam) , this, 1, 0, 1);
```

Option 2 will bind the function to a **specific** value of `someParam` so if it changes it will not be changed in the handler.

Comment: Didn't try the second option, but the first option did work out. Thanks a ton!